# How to check if user is admin then navigate to the following route otherwise 404 component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I have the following route:

```
{
        name: 'product',
        path: 'product/:id',
        component: productEdit,
        props: route => ({
          productId: route.params.productId,
        }),
      },
```

I have several routes and some of them are accessable only for admin. I am getting role check from vuex getter. How can I conditionally check the role from getter and redirect to 404 in vue router file for couple of routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use router hooks and do authorisation as below. Add a meta data for routes that can used to authorise the user.

```
import store from './store'

const routes = [
   { 
      name: 'product',
      path: 'product/:id',
      component: productEdit,
      props: route => ({
        productId: route.params.productId,
      }),
      meta: {
         requiredAuthorization: true, // You can enable/disable authorization 
         roles: ['admin'] // This can be accessed by only admin
      }
   },
   { 
      name: 'other-page',
      path: 'other-page',
      component: OtherPageCompoent
      meta: {
         requiredAuthorization: true,
         roles: ['admin', 'user', 'editor'] // can be accessed by 3 roles
      }
   }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { // This way, you don't need to write hook for each route
  // get where user being stored ex:
  const user = store.getter('user') // assume user have a role with `user.role`
   if (to.meta.requiredAuthorization) {
      if (to.meta?.roles?.includes(user.role))) {
         next()
      } else {
        next('/404-page')
      }
   } else {
      next()
   }
})
```

Comment: How you add getter inside that meta in the first part?

Comment: meta is the static data that can be defined when initialising the routes

Comment: it throws an error 

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Same code is working for me!!, Anyway Can you create a fiddle or reproducible link? will have a look at it

Comment: I have asked new question here with specific issue. :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64503407/vue-router-ignores-meta-when-you-try-directly-access-route-with-params-e-g-pro

Comment: Cool, lemme check

Comment: Thanks Naren it worked. I marked the answer also found issue with redirections it's happening because when you refresh or directly type URL that time getter isAdmin doesn't have value to decide what to do store.watch could solve the problem but it shows the follwong error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64511941/vuex-store-watch-only-accepts-a-function-in-vue-router-guard

Answer (score 1):

You can use navigation guards. From the `vue-router` [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks):

> As the name suggests, the navigation guards provided by `vue-router` are primarily used to guard navigations either by redirecting it or canceling it. There are a number of ways to hook into the route navigation process: globally, per-route, or in-component.

In my applications I typically use a [global `beforeEach` guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) to check privileges for each route. If you only need to protect a few of your routes, [per-route guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) may work better for you.

In either case, if you are using Webpack and define the Vuex store in a standalone file, you can access the store in your navigation guard simply by importing it in the file where the guard is defined.

**EXAMPLE**

Assuming your Vuex store is defined in a file called `store.js`, you could implement per-route guards like this:

```
import store from './store'

//...
//DEFINE OTHER ROUTES..
//...

{
  name: 'product',
  path: 'product/:id',
  component: productEdit,
  props: route => ({
    sourceType: route.params.productId,
  }),
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (store.getters['myGetterName'] == 'admin') {
      next()
    } else {
      next('/notFound') //Redirect to a new "not found" route
    }
  }
},

//Add this route to your routes table, displaying the "not found" component.
{
  name: 'notFound',
  path: 'notFound',
  component: NotFound
},

//FINISH DEFINING YOUR ROUTES...
```

**NOTE**

Semantically, it makes more sense to redirect to a "Forbidden" route when the user doesn't have privileges, rather than "Not Found". You can choose what makes the most sense for your application.

Comment: It looks a bit confusing let's assume I need only include 3 routes with that condition then where should I place them? And where 404 component

Comment: Please see the example I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks I will check it and mark the answer. So for each route that I need to add admin check I need to implement that before each part correct? because Product is divided in several route files and from each file I need one or 2 componnets for hiding

Comment: Yes, add the `beforeEach` function to each route you want to protect. If a lot of your routes need to be protected, it might be better to use a single `beforeEach` function on the `router` instead of one for each route.